# MKStoreKit error

Tags: ios, mkstorekit

I'm trying to follow this [tutorial](http://labs.freescapes.org/blog/tutorials/hitchhikers-guide-to-mkstorekit/) to implement an In-App purchase (productID : PBonnet.TOEIC3.p.

First, I added in MKStoreKitConfigs.h :

```
#define kKlimtPictureSetId @"PBonnet.TOEIC3.Package1"
```

Then, I added my product in MKStoreKitConfigs.plist in non-consumable categorie.

Then, I added in my AppDelegate.m :

```
[MKStoreManager sharedManager];
```

Then, I added in the ViewDidLoad of the ViewController where I want to know if package1 has already  been bought :

```
[MKStoreManager isFeaturePurchased:kKlimtPictureSetId];
```

I get the error :

```
Use of undeclared identifier `MKStoreManager`
```

I've tried to import "appdelegate.m" in my ViewController but it's not found.

I don't get how the method `[MKStoreManager isFeaturePurchased:kKlimtPictureSetId];`has to be used. It has to return a boolean value but how can we access to it ?

Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this line to your `ViewController.h`:

```
#import "MKStoreManager.h"
```

Comment: OK. Thanks. And can I write this : `bool package1bought=[MKStoreManager isFeaturePurchased:kKlimtPictureSetId];` ?

Answer (score 2):

in the v.6

> [[MKStoreKit sharedKit] isProductPurchased:@"you id"];